# Am I missing something? I keep outputting "No file found!"

Tags: c++

```
void getBookData(bookType books[], int& noOfBooks)
{
    ifstream infile;
    string file = "bookData.txt";
    infile.open(file.c_str());
    if (infile.fail()) {
        cout << "No file found!" << endl;
        infile.clear();
    }
    while (true) {
        string line;
        getline(infile, line, '\r');
        if (infile.fail()) {
            break;  
        }
        cout << "Line: " << line << endl;
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

I've tried putting the file in every location I can think of, but somehow it's not loading in. Or, more likely, I'm doing something else wrong. This isn't anything like what the end result of my code is supposed to be like, right now I'm just trying to read out my file line by line.

Comment: Does "every location I can think of" include the same directory as where the program is?

Comment: Make the path to the file absolute, if its not loading then there's something wrong. Otherwise it depends on what compiler you are using, for example in Visual C++ your file should be in the Debug dir if you debug..

Comment: Ya, same directory and one level up...that's all actually, pretty small program I'm working on

Comment: Does your OS have case sensitive filenames?

Comment: Not sure on the file names OSX 10.7

Comment: Or you have no permissions to open said file.

Comment: switched permissions to 777, still no dice

Comment: Well your file is not there or you can't access it, C++ doesn't lie. I would suggest to implement a "fileExist" method based on your OS and call that before opening the file with an ifstream. Then you would be able to get the exact error code and solve your problems.

Comment: I suggest you not test for `fail()` and instead just say `if (!infile) {...}`. This is especially true in your input loop as `fail()` doesn't test the eofbit. Just use `while (getline(...))` when reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you really need help debugging why this is happening to you.

Try adding some more code to your routine to help you determine what is going on. One thing to try is to call `getcwd`.

```
#include <unistd.h>

...
char buf[PATH_MAX];
std::cout << "cwd: " << getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf)) << std::endl;
...
```

This should report to you where your program thinks it is running from.

Start with that first, and I am guessing the next steps will become obvious to you.