# The text file cannot be found

Tags: c, xcode, file

The error says no such file or directory i moved the file to the project folder

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
int i;
char singleline[150];
FILE *file;
file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

 puts(singleline);
if( file == NULL ) {
    perror("Error: ");}
    fclose (file);

}

 return 0;
```

}

Comment: "The error says no such file or directory i moved the file to the project folder" => The file is not in the working directory, point. check twice if there still the error check again and again and again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you really need help debugging why this is happening to you.

Try adding some more code to your routine to help you determine what is going on. One thing to try is to call `getcwd`.

```
#include <unistd.h>

...
char buf[PATH_MAX];
printf("cwd: %s\n", getcwd(buf, sizeof(buf)));
...
```

This should report to you where your program thinks it is running from.

> <sub>You report you get the following output:
>
>   `` cwd: /Users/ahmedhossam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/assem‌​bler-doinswpyuiekhhe‌​mczblkainroaw/Build/‌​Products/Debug `ֿ_\377 ``</sub>

Start with that first, and I am guessing the next steps will become obvious to you.

> <sub>The reported current working directory (hence, `getcwd`) is not your project folder. You can copy your file to that strange directory, or you can use `chdir` to change your working directory to be your project folder, or you can specify the absolute path to your file as suggested below.</sub>

You can avoid the problem altogether by specifying the absolute path to your file.

```
file = fopen("/the/absolute/path/to/test.txt", "r");
```

Comment: If this answer looks familiar to anyone, most of it came from an older answer I gave for C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10924157/315052). Since it was for C++, I didn't mark this question as a dup. But now, I can dup any future similar questions.

Comment: cwd == null what does it mean?

Comment: Did you copy the code above verbatim? You provided a valid `buf` like I did above?

Comment: what should i write  to replace PATH_MAX?

Comment: You can try 8192.

Comment: cwd: /Users/ahmedhossam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/assembler-doinswpyuiekhhemczblkainroaw/Build/Products/Debug
`ֿ_\377

Comment: How should i use this output?

Comment: That is the directory your program is running from. If you want it to run from a different place, try using `chdir()`.

Comment: i just want to open the file called test

Comment: thank you so much for the help it worked))